# Hover Effect Ideas

Tags: css

I'm using a development named "Hover Effect Ideas" (Warm Oscar) available on internet, the purpose of which is to add an effect to hovering an image :
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zapzzE

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

body {
  background: #f6f9fa;
  color: #536d76;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Raleway", Arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: #4f7f90;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #39545e;
}

.grid {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3em 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Common style */

.grid figure {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: -0.135em;
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #3085a3;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.grid figure img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.grid figure figcaption {
  padding: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.grid figure figcaption::before,
.grid figure figcaption::after {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.grid figure figcaption,
.grid figure a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Anchor will cover the whole item by default */


/* For some effects it will show as a button */

.grid figure a {
  z-index: 1000;
  text-indent: 200%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.grid figure h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.grid figure h2 span {
  font-weight: 800;
}

.grid figure h2,
.grid figure p {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid figure p {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 68.5%;
}


/* Individual effects */


/*---------------*/


/***** Oscar *****/


/*---------------*/

figure.effect-oscar {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( 45deg, #22682a 0%, #9b4a1b 40%, #3a342a 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #22682a 0%, #9b4a1b 40%, #3a342a 100%);
}

figure.effect-oscar img {
  opacity: 0.9;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s;
}

figure.effect-oscar figcaption {
  padding: 3em;
  background-color: rgba(58, 52, 42, 0.7);
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.35s;
  transition: background-color 0.35s;
}

figure.effect-oscar figcaption::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  content: "";
}

figure.effect-oscar h2 {
  margin: 20% 0 10px 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}

figure.effect-oscar figcaption::before,
figure.effect-oscar p {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}

figure.effect-oscar:hover h2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

figure.effect-oscar:hover figcaption::before,
figure.effect-oscar:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

figure.effect-oscar:hover figcaption {
  background-color: rgba(58, 52, 42, 0);
}

figure.effect-oscar:hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 69.5em) {
  .grid figure {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .grid figure figcaption {
    font-size: 90%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 41.5em) {
  .grid figure {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">

    <figure class="effect-oscar">
      <img src="https://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/8.jpg" alt="img08" />
      <figcaption>
        <h2><span>Single line</span></h2>
        <p>Oscar is a decent man. He used to clean porches with pleasure.</p>
        <a href="#">View more</a>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure class="effect-oscar">
      <img src="https://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/8.jpg" alt="img08" />
      <figcaption>
        <h2>Here I have <span>two lines</span>or more .......................</h2>
        <p>Oscar is a decent man. He used to clean porches with pleasure.</p>
        <a href="#">View more</a>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure class="effect-oscar">
      <img src="https://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/8.jpg" alt="img08" />
      <figcaption>
        <h2><span>Single line</span></h2>
        <p>Oscar is a decent man. He used to clean porches with pleasure.</p>
        <a href="#">View more</a>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

I have titles  sometimes on one line and sometimes on two lines.

I'm having trouble aligning these titles like this :
[Alignement of titles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKOAR.jpg)

When there are two or more text lines, the titles are shifted.

CSS is not for me! Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `h2` is initially offset from the top using `transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0)`.

This moves the element on the y axis, and is causing a different displacement depending on the overall height of the element (I think).

You could transition the `top` value instead. To do this, add `position: relative` to the `h2`, and give it an initial value (`top: 50px` in the example below). On hover set `top: 0`.

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

body {
  background: #f6f9fa;
  color: #536d76;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Raleway", Arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: #4f7f90;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #39545e;
}

.grid {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3em 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Common style */

.grid figure {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: -0.135em;
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #3085a3;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.grid figure img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.grid figure figcaption {
  padding: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.grid figure figcaption::before,
.grid figure figcaption::after {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.grid figure figcaption,
.grid figure a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Anchor will cover the whole item by default */

/* For some effects it will show as a button */

.grid figure a {
  z-index: 1000;
  text-indent: 200%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.grid figure h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.grid figure h2 span {
  font-weight: 800;
}

.grid figure h2,
.grid figure p {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid figure p {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 68.5%;
}

/* Individual effects */

/*---------------*/

/***** Oscar *****/

/*---------------*/

figure.effect-oscar {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( 45deg, #22682a 0%, #9b4a1b 40%, #3a342a 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #22682a 0%, #9b4a1b 40%, #3a342a 100%);
}

figure.effect-oscar img {
  opacity: 0.9;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s;
}

figure.effect-oscar figcaption {
  padding: 3em;
  background-color: rgba(58, 52, 42, 0.7);
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.35s;
  transition: background-color 0.35s;
}

figure.effect-oscar figcaption::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  content: "";
}

figure.effect-oscar h2 {
  margin: 20% 0 10px 0;
  transition: top 0.35s;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}

figure.effect-oscar figcaption::before,
figure.effect-oscar p {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}

figure.effect-oscar:hover h2 {
  top: 0;
}

figure.effect-oscar:hover figcaption::before,
figure.effect-oscar:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

figure.effect-oscar:hover figcaption {
  background-color: rgba(58, 52, 42, 0);
}

figure.effect-oscar:hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 69.5em) {
  .grid figure {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .grid figure figcaption {
    font-size: 90%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 41.5em) {
  .grid figure {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">

    <figure class="effect-oscar">
      <img src="https://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/8.jpg" alt="img08" />
      <figcaption>
        <h2><span>Single line</span></h2>
        <p>Oscar is a decent man. He used to clean porches with pleasure.</p>
        <a href="#">View more</a>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure class="effect-oscar">
      <img src="https://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/8.jpg" alt="img08" />
      <figcaption>
        <h2>Here I have <span>two lines</span>or more .......................</h2>
        <p>Oscar is a decent man. He used to clean porches with pleasure.</p>
        <a href="#">View more</a>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure class="effect-oscar">
      <img src="https://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/8.jpg" alt="img08" />
      <figcaption>
        <h2><span>Single line</span></h2>
        <p>Oscar is a decent man. He used to clean porches with pleasure.</p>
        <a href="#">View more</a>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```